# I can't find android home icon

Tags: android, xml, icons, png

I donwloaded icon pack from official Android Developer site. I want put in my menu standard home icon but i cant find it Oo

Where i can find this icon in .png? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa1TS.png

Comment: As a note, you probably don't want to place this menu item in your options menu when your app is running on Android 3.0 or later. Instead you should prefer the action bar's home/up button - the activity icon in the upper left of the screen. Tapping it still acts like a menu item click; the MenuItem object passed to your onOptionsItemSelected method will have an ID of android.R.id.home. The button can be enabled implicitly by calling ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) or explicitly on ICS+ by calling ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled(true).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the SDK, for example:

`platforms/android-8/data/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_home.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new image in **Drawables** using **Clip Art** (in clip art library you can find 2 house icons)

And then use that drawable as you would use any other one:

```
R.drawable.ic_home
```